# Correct way to use window.location.href in Polymer 1.1

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

In the index's head I have:

```
  // hashbang is set to true in routing.html
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.href === "/users") {
    console.log('Hey you!');
   }
  </script>
```

I need to implement some class bindings based on `window.location` but I'm testing to make sure it works in polymer. Does it? I does not work for me. When I go to `localhost:3000/#!/users`, noting in console.

Comment: use `href.slice(href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

If you're using page.js with the Polymer starter kit, then all the pages of your app are loaded on the first load.

In this starter kit, changing route with Page.js will display the need page and add `display: none` to hide the other pages.

For example, in your `app/index.html`, you should have something like this:

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
...
  <section data-route="home">
      ...
  </section>


  <section data-route="users">
    ...
  </section>

  <section data-route="user-info">
    ...
  </section>
...
</iron-pages>
```

The `route` parameters on the `iron-pages` element is set by Page.js in `app/elements/routing.html`:

```
page('/', function () {
  app.route = 'home';
});

page('/users', function () {
  app.route = 'users';
});

page('/users/:name', function (data) {
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
});

page('/contact', function () {
  app.route = 'contact';
});
```

So if the route matches `/users` for example, then Page.js will set `app.route = 'users';`, and the iron-pages Polymer element will display the section with `data-route="users"` and hide the other ones without reloading anything, and thus not reloading your script.

**But actually**, since you're using Page.js, it'd be easier to integrate your code in the routing.html file like so:

```
page('/users', function () {
  app.route = 'users';
  console.log('Hey you!');
});

page('/users/:name', function (data) {
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
  console.log('Hey ' + data.params.name);
});

page('/contact', function () {
  app.route = 'contact';
  console.log('Contact page');
});
```

---

You could start by trying to debug, for example, try logging the window href:

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

Which should return:

```
http://localhost:3000/#!/users
```

Then you can have more insight on what your problem is! ;)

Indeed, `window.location.href` gives you the full URL, and it's supposed to do so (with Polymer or not).

On the other hand, `window.location.hash` returns everything in the url starting from the `#` character, giving you `#!/users`, so you could try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Slice(2) to get rid of '#!'
if (window.location.hash.slice(2) === "/users") {
  console.log('Hey you!');
}
</script>
```

**Side note:**

If you have query parameters after the `#`, like so:
`localhost:3000/#!/users?number=42&name=value`

`window.location.href` will then be `#!/users?number=42&name=value`

If you also want to get rid of the query parameters `?number=42&name=value` in such a case, you could write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.hash.slice(2).split("?")[0] === "/users") {
    console.log('Hey you!');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice one. The thing I have is, although this works, if I click on another page and go back to `/users` (button or tab), nothing shows in console. I have to refresh the page. Polymer is using Page.js. Issue there?

Comment: Yes. Yes and more yes! Almouro putting in the routing.html is perfect. Millions of ideas are now popping up because of you. Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha no problem! always happy to help! :)